# Render doesn't match preview?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

So when I preview my render using F12 it shows the color much darker how I want it.

However, when I finish rendering it comes out way brighter.

Purple on left is preview image and right is outcome of render

[image]

Note I am using eevee to render because my computer takes too long using cycles.

Is there a way to accurately view my final render result using eevee because it seems impossible to add proper lighting if I can't get the same result as my preview image?

Comment: there must be a bad setting that explains that, like a hidden light, or Color Management...

Comment: I added an hdri, and removed all my lights and re-render and still looked almost the same as before. I just try to render image on cycles to check and it's so different than eevee, so I don't know why my eevee preview image is not matching my render

Comment: could you please share your file (keep only the important objects)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/f5f0ba3d10af478bbd3c5fed2009eda1 it has a simple 5 frame animation and on preview looks darker, yet after render its still lighter

Comment: You haven't packed the backrgound image so I can't see the effect of the World, if I render it looks close to what I see in preview, but what I see is that in the Render panel > Color Management > View Transform, you have chosen Filmic instead of Standard, maybe try Standard

Comment: oh wow the standard is 1000x better, still like 99% accurate but basically fixes my super bright light issue

Comment: So what is the remaining issue? Maybe pack your image and share your file again

Comment: standard fixes my issue, I was just saying that it solved the lighting issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Render* panel > *Color Management > View Transform*, switch from *Filmic* to *Standard*:

[image]

Comment: so I did a new project today and switched to standard and on preview looks good, but the final render looks super bright again and makes no sense

Comment: maybe check the lights in the Outliner and make sure that you don't have some lights that are disabled in preview but enabled in render

Comment: ah i think it's just impossible to replicate the render without using cycles

Comment: no, it should work fine with Eevee as well, maybe ask a new question and show some screenshots

Comment: hmm okay I'll add a new question